# Finding computational complexity of genetic algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, genetic-algorithm

How can I find the computational complexity of a genetic algorithm? I would appreciate any ideas or examples.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the computational complexity of a genetic algorithm is no different than finding the computational complexity of any other algorithm. You have two options:

1. Evaluate your code - go through line by line and consider how much time and memory each operation will take.
2. Time your code (and measure memory usage) with different input sizes to experimentally figure out how it scales (note that this will tell you only average-case complexity, unless you specifically know and test on the best and worst cases).

Some general genetic algorithm specific guidelines:

- For a generational genetic algorithm (i.e. one with non-overlapping generations), the time complexity will be at least O(population size * number of generations). Most steady-state genetic algorithms (i.e. those which have a single population which things are added to or removed from over time) will have a similar time complexity, but this is not guaranteed.
- The memory complexity for any genetic algorithm needs to be at least O(population size), but can be much larger.
- In many cases, evaluating the fitness function is the expensive step of the computation, and so the run-time of various genetic algorithms isa often compared in terms of the number of evaluations that they require to find a good solution.

Comment: Thanks seaotternerd.  As in GA we work with randomly selected ,individuals Can we use regression techniques for this purpose?

Comment: For the purpose of picking individuals or estimating tune complexity? Assuming you mean the latter, yes, you can use regression techniques to infer the complexity based on experimental data. Just make sure not to assume the relationship is linear if it's not.

Comment: Yes,that's what I meant-Thank you!